# I have a pdf generated from a binary string in the database that always returns as corrupt through PHP

Tags: php, pdf

The bianry string is returned from the database and then passed to the browser by using the correct header changes through PHP. The returned file always comes back as corrupt however when I look at the actual file in notepad the first part of it does seem to be correct but then the text goes a bit crazy. I have uploaded the file so you can see what I mean. Any indication as to why the browser would interpret the binary incorrectly would be much appreciatied.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3435192/apdf44-3.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer was relating to the mssql connection. The default "max text size" for a blob returned from mssql to php is 66KB. You can change this in php.ini. The file was not corrupt it was just incomplete due to file size restrictions by this. As soon as the text size limit was increase the whole file was downloaded and it worked correctly